# Crawler4J does not detect encoding with Tika with sbt-assembly in FatJar

Tags: apache-tika, crawler4j

Using Crawler4j in sbt console works. When using sbt-assembly to create a fatjar Tika (?) no longer seems to be able to detect encoding of pages when started with

```
 java -jar crawler.jar
```

What is Tika missing to detect the encoding?

```
ERROR edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.parser.Parser - Failed to detect the character
encoding of a document, while parsing
```

Merge strategy is

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the merge strategy, works now with the standard strategy. Got that one from a bad example.